# Convert a string into shell arguments

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, bash, shell

I'm interested how is parsed the bash input into arguments.

For example, by using `process.argv` we get an array of strings in NodeJS (but this is language agnostic).

My question is how can I parse an input like `"node foo.js --foo "bar baz" -b foo"` into an array like `process.argv` (or the equivalent in other languages) returns (e.g. `["node", "foo.js", "--foo", "\"bar baz\"", "-b", "foo"]`?

Splitting by space is not enough (because of the quotes). Is it possible with some more complicated regex to handle the quotes and getting such an array?

Comment: You'd have to write a parser that mimics shell syntax. What is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Pointy Actually that *parser* is most probably a regular expression to handle the quotes. I'm working on a command line arguments parser which is almost finished and it accepts arrays like `process.argv`. But what I'm trying to do is to make it accept strings (bash commands like this example) and convert them into arrays internally.

Comment: I seriously doubt it. The shell parser has to deal with different kinds of quotes, variable expansion, file redirection, etc.

Comment: @Pointy I really don't need file redirection or other things like that (suppose that they were been already handled by bash itself). What I do need is a simple converter of a command that the user gives to my library into an array, by escaping the quotes in a way that bash does.

Comment: bash doesn't "escape" quotes. It parses commands. You need to do the same thing so you need a shell parser. Yours can likely be simpler then the shell's because you don't need to handle some things the shell does but you need to know which things those are (and what your supported shell subset actually is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a regex solution seems to be explicitly requested, while this is the kind of task for a proper parser, here's a regex one-liner for the thrills.

Considering the specifications:

- JS-compatible
- Tokenize by spaces but keep `"..."` or `'...'` together

An simple `match` function can be used to find values, with the downside that nested escaping of quotes will not be detected well (Recursive matching has been difficult with regexes.)

```
>>> str = "node foo.js --foo \"bar baz\" -b foo";
    str.match(/"[^"]+"|'[^']+'|\S+/g)
<<< ["node", "foo.js", "--foo", "\"bar baz\"", "-b", "foo"]
```

**(Simplified) Regex explanation:**

- `"[^"]+"|'[^']+'` is a subpattern that looks for pairs of quotes with anything other than the quotes themselves in between.
- `|` Alternates to another option.
- `\S` is a negation for `\s`: It matches non-whitespace sequences, which effectively asserts we match tokens which aren't previously collected. The `+` quantifies the entire string.

Comment: Both answers are good, but like I said, I need a tiny solution for tiny problems. Could you please mention cases when this will not work properly?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Problems may arise when there are escaped quotes in a token, for example: `"\"foo \\\"qux quux\\\" bar\""` Aside from that, everything should work along the way, including a cross-usage of both quotes: `"\"foo 'bar' baz\""`

Comment: Nice, nice, nice! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

Using the [shell-quote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shell-quote) NPM package will handle this.

```
var parse = require('shell-quote').parse;
parse('node foo.js --foo "bar baz" -b foo');

[ 'node', 'foo.js', '--foo', 'bar baz', '-b', 'foo' ]
```

Comment: This is a nice library. However, I'm still looking for a pure regex solution for simple cases (spaces and quotes, and simple quotes).